# What metadata can be captured by a single miner? What about a group of miners?

Tags: blockchain, network, privacy, transaction-propagation

It is my understanding that the blockchain consist of the following information for every transaction in the network:

- From address
- To address
- Amount of bitcoins

What additional information can a miner collect? For example, is it easy to find the IP address that the transaction was first sent from? Is there other identifying information a single or group of miners can capture? What roll do bitcoin tumblers play in all this?

Answer (score 3):

The sender, recipient and transferred amount are already public information and readily available in the blockchain.

The only special access that miners have is that they could log the ip address of users that directly submit transactions for mining, if such a direct access is offered. Besides that there is no special information available to miners.

Comment: The time a block was first seen (not the time transcribed in the block) is information available to each miner, and you can also learn what version of software the block sender is advertising.

Comment: That's not unique to miners but true for every full node.